# An Einstein summation problem

Tags: summation, tensors

Is the expression $(T_{abc}+T_{cab}+T_{bca})X^aX^bX^c$ equal to $3T_{abc}X^aX^bX^c$, using Einstein summation notation, even if we allow a,b,c to range over different values? I understand that they are probably equal if $a,b,c$ range over the same values, but I do not think that $\sum_a\sum_b\sum_c T_{abc}X^aX^bX^c$ is always equal to $\sum_a\sum_b\sum_c T_{cab}X^aX^bX^c$ if $a,b,c$ range over different values. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As you thought, if they range over different values, this is not true. For instance, take the sum
$$\sum_{a=1}^1 \sum_{b=1}^1 \sum_{c=1}^2 =3T_{111}X^{1}X^{1}X^{1} + (T_{112} + T_{121} + T_{211})X^{1}X^{1}X^{2}$$
and it is not necessary that the last term is equal to $3T_{111}X^{1}X^{1}X^{2}$ since it is necessary that the $T_{ijk}$ are equal.